# Writing an ORM using Reflection cannot properly cast

Tags: c#, reflection, orm

So I am writing, strictly for personal learning, an ORM in C#.  I am looping through a database, where the column names match the properties of a class.  I am then looping through the properties of the class and assigning the corresponding database column values but i am running into issues casting the return value from the database column.

```
var PropCollection = type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo Property in PropCollection)
{
    Property.SetValue(_t, DReader[Property.Name].ToString(),null);
}
```

I get the expected error:

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Int32'.

Where DReader is just an SQLDataReader returning a column value inside of a loop, say this value is an int, how do I cast it as such??

```
Property.GetType();
```

correctly knows the type I need but how do I use that to cast `DReader[Property.Name]`?

Comment: Depending on what the "rules" of your ORM are, you could just remove the `.ToString()` - but: since you are using `SetValue` you don't really need to cast...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` can handle all straight conversions.

You should not use `DReader[Property.Name].ToString()` in your loop. Remove the `ToString()`.

```
var PropCollection = type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo Property in PropCollection)
{
    var value = DReader[Property.Name];
    if (!Property.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, Property.GetType());

    Property.SetValue(_t, value, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow Convert was completely lacking from my C# vocabulary!